# sudo apache2 stop doesn't work

Tags: django, ubuntu, apache2, amazon-web-services

not sure why but when I run:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-46-206-16:/etc/init.d$ sudo apache2 stop
Usage: apache2 [-D name] [-d directory] [-f file]
               [-C "directive"] [-c "directive"]
               [-k start|restart|graceful|graceful-stop|stop]
               [-v] [-V] [-h] [-l] [-L] [-t] [-S] [-X]
Options:
  -D name            : define a name for use in <IfDefine name> directives
  -d directory       : specify an alternate initial ServerRoot
  -f file            : specify an alternate ServerConfigFile
  -C "directive"     : process directive before reading config files
  -c "directive"     : process directive after reading config files
  -e level           : show startup errors of level (see LogLevel)
  -E file            : log startup errors to file
  -v                 : show version number
  -V                 : show compile settings
  -h                 : list available command line options (this page)
  -l                 : list compiled in modules
  -L                 : list available configuration directives
  -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS  : show parsed settings (currently only vhost settings)
  -S                 : a synonym for -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS
  -t -D DUMP_MODULES : show all loaded modules 
  -M                 : a synonym for -t -D DUMP_MODULES
  -t                 : run syntax check for config files
  -X                 : debug mode (only one worker, do not detach)
```

it doesn't seem to stop the server. I still trying to ping the ip and it's returning the default page. Is there a reason why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 sudo service apache2 stop
```

See here:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP

The older way would be:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
```

Note that when you do `sudo apache2 stop`, you are running `apache2` from you PATH, not from the current folder (usually, `.` is not in the PATH). Try `sudo ./apache2 stop` for that.

See here:

- http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-start-restart-stop-apache-web-server/

Answer (score 1):

This is not a programming question. I guess you have to look for answers here http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

You have to type full path to apache2 init script. Example:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
```

Answer (score 0):

check ubuntu@ip-10-46-206-16:/etc/init.d$ ./apache2 stop

this will slove your problem

Answer (score 0):

One thing is missing in the command, I encountered the same issue:

```
sudo apache2 stop
```

Should be

```
sudo service apache2 stop
```

Hope no one search too far for missing **service** part of the command :)